# How should I respond to a channel message?

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

Right now I have a background thread that I'm communicating with using a channel. The details aren't important but I have an `enum Message` with a variant `Variant(Data, Sender<Response>)`, so that in the background thread I can do:

```rust
loop {
    match message_rx.recv() {
        Ok(Message::Variant(data, sender)) => {
            let result = do_something(data);
            sender.send(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the foreground thread(s),

```rust
let (response_rx, response_tx) = flume::bounded(1);
message_tx.send(Message::Variant(data, response_tx));
let response = response_rx.recv();
```

This solution is not concurrent (nor is concurrency a particular goal here) but is it in fact a solution? I was inspired by the Erlang pattern where a process sends its pid with a message so it can receive a response.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution (but you're not describing your problem very precisely). Is there anything that makes you think this is not a solution? Possibly, I'd replace the response channel with a oneshot to make clear that there will only be one response — but you'll have to add another dependency.

Comment: Do you need to pass the sender as part of the message? Would it be possible to initialize it before you create a receiver thread and move it into it?

Comment: this would be more suitable for code review stackexchange

Comment: @Caesar Nothing in particular, it just feels like a hack.

Comment: @KonstantinGrech It would not, as there could be any number of sending threads

Comment: @ZackH You can always clone the sender and pass it to any number of threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a pattern, as in your example, embedding a reply communication channel within the  message is a good way of doing it,

You can find different utilities for it, for example in an asynchronous environment using tokio, you could use [`oneshot`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html), which is a channel that ensures a single message, from the [example](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html#examples):

```rust
use tokio::sync::oneshot;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(_) = tx.send(3) {
            println!("the receiver dropped");
        }
    });

    match rx.await {
        Ok(v) => println!("got = {:?}", v),
        Err(_) => println!("the sender dropped"),
    }
}
```